# Angular Velocity by Vector - 2D

Tags: software

This is originally a problem in programming, but since almost no one on Stackoverflow know how to solve this I went here instead; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003612/javascript-angular-velocity-by-vector-2d

I want to convert X and Y velocities to angular velocity, this is the formula I am currently using to calculate the initial velocity by the x and y values and then turn it into angular velocity for my circle object:

Av = Sqrt(Vx^2 + Vy^2) / R

Angularvelocity = Squareroot of (Velocity x^2 + Velocity y^2) / Circle's radius

This is how it simulates in my programming: http://jsfiddle.net/yzb9P/2/ (Click to change the balls position)

Now since a square root can't be negative, this won't work when the ball is supposed to rotate anti-clockwise. So, I need a signed version of the initial velocity that also can be negative, how do I calculate that?

I've heard about that the Wedge product is working for this, and I've read many articles about it too, but I still don't understand how to use it, please help!

Comment: If no one here can answer you, you may want to try http://SciComp.StackExchange.com

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Can the ball slip?

Comment: What you can try is to project (e.g. with linear algebra) the velocity vector along the plane the ball is rolling on. If the ball can't slip, that should be proportional to spin; if it slips, their derivatives may be proportional. that kind of depends on whether you're making a really accurate demo or a game.

Answer (score 1):

The angular velocity vector can be computed via the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the position and velocity vectors:
$$
\boldsymbol\omega=\frac{\mathbf r\times\mathbf v}{|\mathbf r|^2}\tag{1}
$$
In two dimensions, this is really
$$
\mathbf a\times\mathbf b=\det(\mathbf{a\,b})=a_xb_y - a_yb_x
$$

I don't really know Java well at all, but it looks like your code is already equipped with computing the cross product (`wedge: function(v)`). But note that your line

```
ball.av = ball.v.wedge(ball.v.length())/ball.r
```

Seems to be the problem area. Given the definition of `wedge`, this should have a negative sign in front as $\mathbf r\times\mathbf v=-\mathbf v\times\mathbf r$. It is also unclear to me how `ball.v.length()` and `ball.r` are related..

Comment: "ball.av = ball.v.wedge(ball.v.length())/ball.r" Is totally wrong actually is returns Error, I just forgot it there, yes you are right, a vector is supposed to be the input, not a number. I mean if for eg: Vx = -3 and Vy = 2, the pythagoras theorem won't work. It's not really the computation of the angular velocity, it's more about getting the initial velocity by the Vx and Vy, and also if they're negative.

Comment: Also I don't understand what a and b means

Comment: $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are generic vectors

Comment: ok... I still don't understand really how I am supposed to fix this in my code, but I need something like pythagoras that also works with negative values, such as wedge, I mean "ball.v.wedge(ball.v)" just returns 0 :(

Comment: But I still don't understand how to use Wedge, and how to implement it to this situation

Comment: Of course `ball.v.wedge(ball.v)=0`, the cross product of anything with itself is identically zero.

Comment: And how are you supposed to use it correctly?

Comment: You need the cross product of position with velocity: `w=x*v_y - y*v_x`

Comment: Are you even keeping track of `x` and `y` in the object `ball`?

Comment: Yes, ball.c is the vector for the position and ball.v for the velocity, though I tried ball.c.wedge(ball.v) but it just screws up :(

Comment: It should think it would be `ball.av=ball.c.wedge(ball.v)/ball.c.length`

Comment: Rotation of ball is defined by radians though..

Comment: When I try modifying the code, the cross in the middle of the ball disappears so I can't confirm these changes

Comment: use .length() not .length

Comment: Does it work?¨¨

Comment: Aha, that worked, I see the cross now.

Comment: And it seems to be rotating both directions.

Comment: How do you determine where on the ball the user clicked?

Comment: failed right?¨¨

Comment: No it doesn't it just sets the balls center position to the mouse's whenever you click somewhere, and the velocity isn't affected or the rotation just the position

Comment: I only ask because it is rotating at some crazy speeds because I'm now basing it on the position on the board (`ball.c`). It the position for `ball.av` should be based on where the mouse was clicked on the ball.

Comment: No I just want the center.

Comment: Hmm. Well it works for me (rotation in both directions) using `ball.av = ball.c.wedge(ball.v)/ball.c.length()` It is just rotating at insanely fast speeds compared to what you had before.

Comment: just insane? how should I make it perfect?

Comment: ball.v.wedge(ball.c) / ball.c.length() / ball.r

Comment: This works? / ball.r and reverse order of ball.v and ball.c

Comment: If you want your work to be wrong, go ahead and do that. Reversing the order of `ball.v` and `ball.c` is inherently wrong due to the order of the cross product. Dividing by an extra position term means that your units are $m^{-1}s^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, I see myself it's a biit wrong to slow rotation, but how are you supposed to fix it then?

Comment: Ok, I checked with the circumference, ball.v.wedge(ball.c) / ball.c.length() / ball.r is wrong

Comment: But hasn't the radius in some kinda way also to be in the formula?

Comment: The $\mathbf r$ is the *position vector* of the rotation, not necessarily the radius

Comment: in my code ball.r is the radius

Comment: soo.. how is it going?

Comment: I'm trying but haven't found any solution yet

Comment: ball.c.wedge(ball.v) / ball.c.length() Why is it spinning soo fast?

Comment: Not really sure why it's spinning so fast.

Comment: Isn't the radius supposed to be in some place in the formula then?

Comment: W = V / R ¨¨¨¨¨¨

Comment: Again, that r is the *position vector* and not the necessarily radius of the disk.

Comment: Aha now I get it, (feel so stupid)

Comment: but how are you supposed to do the formula then?

Comment: To make it spin in the correct speed and right direction?

Comment: AHH THIS IS DRIVINF ME CRAAAZY!

Comment: @Murplyx I'm not sure what your physics background is, but it would certainly help you right now to study some basic vector algebra. It sounds like you aren't very familiar with vectors and the cross product, and until you learn those basics, we can't do much to help you.

Comment: I just need the formula, that's it

Comment: I especially not familiar with a problem like this :(

Comment: @Draksis As if you haven't said that many times enought, but seriously I need help with this

Comment: He's given you the formula in his answer. The problem is intrinsically a vector problem, since you're working in two dimensions. (By the way, to add something to a previous comment, you can hit the "Edit" button rather than posting multiple times in close succession.)

Comment: He has given me a formula for half the question, the whole question we haven't solved yet, because then I'd check the accept button.

Comment: Think I found a solution.. http://jsfiddle.net/yzb9P/6/ Is this correct? It seems like that, but you're the master, I mean is it calculated correctly? (line 233)

Comment: It reacts a lot better now, though it seems to still be a little wonky at borders. It actually slowed to a stop *before reaching the bottom* on the right wall several times for me.

Comment: @Murplyx Did you read my answer to your duplicate on scicomp.stackexchange? If you're going to double post you should probably keep up with the answers to both http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11353/angular-velocity-by-vector-2d

Comment: I also added an modified jsfiddle script that fixes the unnatural rolling behavior for the ball.